# A simple question about mfpic coordinates

Tags: coordinates

I'm learning a little mfpic. I have the following code that draws just a line and
I just need to know the meaning of the coordinates: [15]{-7}{6}{-3}{3}

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}

\begin{document}

\mfpicnumber{1}
\opengraphsfile{Myfig001}

\begin{mfpic}[15]{-7}{6}{-3}{3}
\polyline{(-6,0),(5,0)}
\end{mfpic}


\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

Comment: See p.12 of the package documentation: `[⟨xfactor⟩][⟨yfactor⟩]{⟨xmin⟩}{⟨xmax⟩}{⟨ymin⟩}{⟨ymax⟩}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the doc.

Comment: I still need a simple explanation in simple words. Would appreciate any help.